# How to resize image dynamically , both horizontally and vertically when the browser window resizes

Tags: image, resize

I can do the resize either vertically or horizontally, but not both
I am trying to get something like you find on this site, but the code there is way behind my understanding

http://www.clorimages.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just Supply The Percentage to the image like

```
<img style="width:95%;height:85%" src="image_source" />
```

Check Following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L86F5/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works nicely with horizontal image, but stretches the portraits. I am trying to find a solution that can be used with both orientation automatically